# Iterate a list from second to last and then first element

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I need to create for loop which iterate list from second element to the last and then it take first elements. Something like this:

```
x = [2, 133, 24]

for i in (x[1:] + x[0]):
     print(i)
```

result should be: 133, 24, 2

list cannot be changed and should be usable on lists with 2-10 elements
Thanks for Your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small adjustment

```
for i in (x[1:] + [x[0]]):
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modulo

```
x = [2, 133, 24]

start = 1
end = 3
for i in range(start,end+start):
    index = i % end
    print(x[index])
```

Comment: This doesn't do what op asked for...

Comment: that's better, but doesn't work for longer lists.

Comment: Just fixed it, works with longer list now

Comment: it requires you to set `end` manually, but yea